# How to check if a key has been released using keystates SDL

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, sdl

How can I see if a key is released via keystates in sdl.

```
const Uint8 *keystate = SDL_GetKeyboardState(NULL);

if (keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_UP])
{
    renderer();
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to store and update every frame a list of states for the keys you are interested. A key is released if it was pressed in the previous frame and it is not pressed in this frame.

Comment: So are you saying I should set it up like: if (!keystate[SDL_SCANCODE_UP])
{
}

Comment: Aha! I got it to work with your information. Thanks!